# CSS position float

Tags: html, css

I try to display a left and right area but it's not working actually with the cotes "right" and "left"

I tried the `position :absolute` but it's display me something strange

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my conteneur div or my div `element1`

Someone knows how I can achieve that?

```css
#conteneur {
  padding-top: -25px;
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#element1 {
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteneur">

  <div id="element1">
    <img src="{{ public_path('../public/uploads/logo-FFRXIII-2017-01.png')}}" style="max-width: 300px;">

    <div id="right">
      adresse_right
    </div>

    <div id="left">
      adresse_left
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'padding` with `negative` values never works. Its  invalid + can you explain with a demo image, what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: `.left` and `.right` are looking for classes you are using ids. Change to `#left` and `#right`.

Comment: still the same actually i get : adresse_left and adresse_right under two lines . would would like to display in the same line but one to the left and one to the right

Comment: You've also made them `width: 100%;` so there is no space for them to float left or right.

Comment: i changed width to 50% but still the same effect

Comment: ok now it's work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your

```
<div id="right">
  adresse_right
</div>

<div id="left">
  adresse_left
</div>
```

Won't react to your `CSS` since these are ID's and in your `CSS` you are trying to find `classes` with the `.` selector. So change the `.` to a `#` or change your `ID` tags to `Classes`.

Secondly i've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmu4x7pL/10/) and edited your code hope this helps!

Comment: @MathieuMourareau No problem, please set my answer as the correct answer so that in the future others that have the same kind of problem can find the solution easier

Comment: this  fiddle still has `padding:-25px` which is invalid

Comment: @dippas `padding` is removed, Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 3):

you are using `flexbox`, so stick with `flexbox` and forget `floats`

```css
#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.img {
  flex: 0 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteneur">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    adresse_right
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    adresse_left
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i will try now !!

Comment: It works, and yes you are right, it's better to keep using `flex-box` then what i did. @MathieuMourareau This is the best and correct answer. Please change the correct answer from mine to this answer.

Comment: not sure if flexbox will work to the html because it's to export via PDF ! i need to try ! i keep u update